# How to add JavaScript variable as CSS value in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to put footer at bottom.I get screen height by js and put this value in a variable. Now i want to put this variable in css height.(How can i apply height 700px to heightscr, please see code below)
Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function footerlocation(){
        var heightscr=(screen.availHeight); 

        var myElement = document.querySelector(".container");
        myElement.style.height = "700px";
        myElement.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";        
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Note that the `()` you have around `screen.availHeight` don't do anything.

Comment: I am unsure if `screen.availHeight` does anything at all. You give anything in JS a value with an `=` operator. LHS (left hand side) becomes what follows the operator, so: `myelement.height = heightscr` would make myelement's height property the value of heighsc variable.

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation:

```
myElement.style.height = heightscr + "px";
```

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder for help me.I got what i want. Thnks